# Creating a reset and reload global function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that will clear all of my forms (inputs and selects) on the same page and reload the window(refresh the page) that is global and can be called anywhere in my JavaScript or JQUERY. How do I make it global so that it may be used anywhere?

```
function resetAndReload () {
    $('#myform')[0].reset();
    $('#myform1')[0].reset();
    $('#myform2')[0].reset();
    $('#myform3')[0].reset();
    window.location.reload();
    }

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#button").click(function(){
        resetAndReload();
    });

});
```

Comment: Aren't all the forms reset anyway on the page refresh?

Comment: You could just call `window.location.reload(true);` to force it to reload the forms.

Comment: @Stryner Awesome, I didn't know reload accepted a parameter. Its one of those functions you never really read up about.

Comment: window.location.reload(true); did not clear the input values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pure Javascript it is as simple as this:

```
for(var i = 0, f = document.querySelectorAll('form'); i < f.length; i++) 
    f.item(i).reset()
```

You could wrap this in a global function:

```
function resetForms(selector){
    for(var i = 0, f = document.querySelectorAll(selector || 'form'); i < f.length; i++) f.item(i).reset()
}
```

By passing it a selector you could even target specific forms:

```
resetForms('#myFormWithId');
```

or

```
resetForms('.registration form[data-resetable]');
```

Also, reloading your window *is* already a global function, being tied to the `window.location` object, so why not call that as is? You do not need to reinvent the wheel here.

#### Update

As @Stryner mentioned in the comments, if you are reloading you can force it to reload a server fetched version of your page by passing the `true` bool flag to the reload function as such: `window.location.reload(true);` - this should clear your forms as well.

Comment: window.location.reload(true); did not clear the input values

Comment: @ZaneZ It was worth a try, in essence it could work. I am unsure how you keep the values though, a reload usually clears forms, but the other code provided works well.